# Conditional Import and Export in Javascript

Tags: javascript, import, ecmascript-6

I want to import two objects from different files based on some conditions, and export the imported object with different name:

```
if(condition1)
    import {obj3, obj4} from './file1';
else
    import {obj5, obj6} from './file2';

export {obj1, obj2}
```

Comment: you can try the factory pattern for this.

Comment: concwerning the rename, you can use the **as** syntax

Comment: In a project, I wanted to free my app from Sentry's logging capability while it was in development mode. So I did this and it works on my App.js.

`export default __DEV__ ? App : Sentry.wrap(App)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could have an intermediate importer/exporter that re-export a given import based on a condition, like this:

```
//exportSelector.js;
import {obj1, obj2}
let exportedObj = condition1 ? obj1 : obj2;
export exportedObj;

//import.js
import exportedObj;
```